# Display user and logout in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How can I make the html page display the user who is logged in? So I mean how can I display the username which is used to login in to the website? Besides this I would like to know how I can logout from my webpage?

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");


if (isset($_POST['inloggen'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $rpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['rpassword']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' AND rpassword = '$rpassword'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        header('location: loggedin.php');
    } else {
        header('location: error.php');
    }

    echo "<br />";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/java.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SBRM National Bank</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">SBRM National Bank</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Particulier</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Persoonlijk</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privé</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Zakelijk</a></li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Registeren</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>  Inloggen</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid hero-slide">
      <div class="row">
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide " data-ride="carousel">



      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="images/login.jpg" alt="Ad">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 class="caption">Inloggen</h3>

        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="container padding-top-10">
  <div class="panel col-md-6">
    <div class="panel-heading "><h5>Inloggen</h5></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form action="" method="post">
<label for="username" class="control-label">Gebruikersnaam:</label>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Gebruikersnaam" name="username" requierd/>
          </div>
        </div>
<label for="password" class="control-label">Wachtwoord:</label>
        <div class="row ">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Wachtwoord" name="password" requierd/>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Herhaal Wachtwoord" name="rpassword" requierd/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2 padding-top-10">
            <input type="submit" name="inloggen" class="btn btn-succes" value="Login">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 padding-top-10">
            <p class="pleft">Door op <b>login</b> te klikken, gaat u akkoord met de <a class="algemeen" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#t_and_c_m">Algemene Voorwaarden</a> opgesteld door deze site.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


  <div class="modal fade" id="t_and_c_m" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Algemene Voorwaarden</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Deze algemene voorwaarden zijn tot stand gekomen in overleg
tussen de Nederlandse Vereniging van Banken en de Consumentenbond
in het kader van de Coördinatiegroep Zelfreguleringsoverleg
van de Sociaal-Economische Raad en treden in werking
per 1 november 2009. Over overige (product)voorwaarden die
van toepassing kunnen zijn heeft geen overleg plaatsgevonden.
De Consumentenbond behoudt zich het recht tot collectieve
actie voor met betrekking tot dergelijke voorwaarden.</p>
      </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ik ga akkoord</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h6>Copyright &copy; 2016</h6>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="boss">Sander Bakker</li>
          <li class="unstyled">Bob Lansbergen</li>
          <li class="unstyled">Ronald van den Heuvel</li>
          <li class="unstyled">Max Donck</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <h6>Over Ons</h6>
        <p id="pfont">Dit is een website ontworpen om een banksysteem te simuleren met PHP en mySQL</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h6>Navigatie</h6>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Particulier</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Persoonlijk</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Privé</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Zakelijk</a></li>
        </uL>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h6>Contact</h6>
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Google +</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li class="unstyled"><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
        </uL>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
  </body>
  </head>
  </html>
```

This is the code I'm using. The other question doesn't anwser mine because he uses PDO and I use MySQLi. I find it hard to get a link beteween those two diffent PHP structures.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display username once user has logged in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829580/display-username-once-user-has-logged-in)

Comment: Well.. without the slightest idea of what you're actually using, we cant redirect you to any related information.

Comment: Hi Sander. Please mark as answered your previous questions (when there is a valid answer), before posting new question. Thank you.

Comment: @fusion3k I've done that just a minute ago. Sorry I'm new here

Comment: @paskl Look at my code just posted it

Comment: Use `$_SESSION`. Destroy it to log out.

Comment: "*..The other question doesn't awnser mine because he uses PDO and I use MySQLi.*" ~ But, Logic Are Same. Isn't It ?

Comment: We don't need logic @NanaPartykar! ;-)

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a `username session` in **login**. And, check whether the user is logged in or not. Check below code.:

```
<?php
session_start();
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "login");


if (isset($_POST['inloggen'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['password']);
    $rpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['rpassword']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' AND rpassword = '$rpassword'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {

        // First create one session username like this after login.
        $rowUsers = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $_SESSION['username'] = $rowUsers['username'];

        header('location: loggedin.php');
    } else {
        header('location: error.php');
    }

    echo "<br />";
}
?>



<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li><a href="register.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Registeren</a></li>
    //Check whether user is logged in or not.
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {?>
    <li class="active"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?></li>
    <?php }
    else {?>
  <li class="active"><a href="login.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>Inloggen</a></li>
    <?php }?>
</ul>
```

Comment: So the first part of the code belongs to the login.php and the other part belongs to the loggedin.php? Sorry it is a little bit confusing by this.

Comment: This is the same page which you have given. Just replace this code with your code in that position. @SanderBakker

Comment: If I do that it only works on the login.php page? I want it to work on every page from the moment your are logged in..

Comment: Then, you have to keep it in all pages. Ideally, create one header.php page. Where all your head part will be there. include this header.php page in all pages. Why to give in all pages @SanderBakker

Comment: "*.. it only works on the login.php page*" ~ It worked then why you said it's confusing. Your code structure is confusing @SanderBakker if you have written all those code in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

On this file, since you have already started session, do this:

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['logged_user'] = $username; //Add this row
    header('location: loggedin.php');
} else {
```

Then, on the `loggedin` page, do this:

```
session_start(); //must be declared before the usage of any $_SESSION variables
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_user']))
echo "Welcome, " . $_SESSION['logged_user'];
```

To logout, you would do:

```
session_destroy();
```

Comment: I don't understand it, I've added the first line to my login.php file. I wanted to display the username on the loggedin.php page so I pasted the second line on the loggedin.php page. Like this '<li class-"active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span>  <?php echo "Welcome, " . $_SESSION['logged_user'];?></a></li>' After this it won't work I got the error Undefined variable

Comment: You must do `session_start()` on the loggedin page. And also you must add the first row before you redirect to loggedin, inside the if

Comment: So I need to add the code from the login.php to the loggedin.php for it to work or am I wrong ?

Comment: I'll update my answer. Check it out.